# Remove problems in problems tab VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

There are problems in my problems tab that I just need deleted. I don't care for them they're adding highlights to my code. I don't need them don't want them but can't delete them.

Why can't I just right-click delete the problems in this tab? It's poor design. I've tried restarting the client, the window, even re-opening this code. The problems are "latched" on with no option to remove.

I'm not trying to remove the highlights. I'm trying to remove the problems itself.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be any built in functionality to only remove the problems without removing the highlighting also.

It probably depends on the language server being used, but you can customize *which* problems you see.  For example, take this Python code:

```py
import MyModule

print(myVariable)
```

[image: image showing python code with problems]

`MyModule` produces a *reportMissingImports* problem, and `myVariable` produces a *reportUndefinedVariable* problem.  If you are using Pylance as your Python language server, there is a setting called `python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides` that you can use to turn off specific problems (or change their severity).  The problem is, you will also lose the highlighting as I mentioned.

Example of the JSON setting for this:

```json
"python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
  "reportUndefinedVariable": "none",
  "reportMissingImports": "none"
}
```

So depending on what programming language you are using, you can probably configure the problems as such.  If you are perhaps seeing a lot of the same "pointless" problems that you don't care about, it may be worth turning that problem off (i.e. set its severity to `none`).

Comment: Thanks for the info but this isn't the answer. Sadly I know what the answer is. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/66982 it's been requested for years and intermittently closed or abandoned